# How to check if a specific value is in a range?

Tags: c#, epplus

I'm trying to check if the current value of the cell is in between `25` and `40, what I did so far:

```
var address = new ExcelAddress("H:Y");
var condition = ws.ConditionalFormatting.AddExpression(address);
condition.Style.Font.Color.Color = Color.Red;
condition.Formula = string.Format("IF(G2 < 25 AND G2 <= 40, 1, 0)", 1);
```

The problem's that when I export the file I get a corrupted xlsx, why?

Comment: Is the Excel file still corrupted if you comment out the last line?

Comment: @MihaiOvidiuDrăgoi nope, if I comment the Formula line it isn't corrupted

Comment: `string.Format("IF(G2 < 25 AND G2 <= 40, 1, 0)", 1);` This doesn't make sense. 1.) It is true for G2 < 25 it should be G2 > 25 and 2.) You use string.Format but you haven't used a format placeholder ("{0}" )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AND is not an operator in Excel, it is a function. You need to write it like this:

```
condition.Formula = "IF(AND(G2 > 25, G2 <= 40), 1, 0)";
```

Comment: I replaced with your formula syntax, still the file is corrupted, could you please check here: https://pastebin.com/f9NdxSX6

Comment: it looks like in every case (5 separate times) you have unbalanced parentheses. If you write them as I have above, it should work.

Comment: i didn't test, but this looks right to me: https://pastebin.com/XvutmmjE

Comment: Just a question: any reason why I get also H1 untile Y1 row colored? I specify to check H2 but the code will color also H1, I1, L1, why?

Comment: You use "H:Y" as your range. It will color everything in that range (H through Y) based on value in G2. If you just want to set "H2" then pass that into ExcelAddress()

Comment: If I set as excel address H2:Y2 the color will be applied only on the second row